# No Unity after ubuntu 12.10 upgrade

Tags: unity, drivers, 12.10, ati, graphics

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04, there was low graphics and no Unity. Just the mouse and the wallpaper.
So, I got into the terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, launched Chrome and searched for a solution. As a result, I tried this:

```
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run
```

It did not work. Then I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

It did not work too. I removed the repository, got back the the xorg version to 1.13, and tried this:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh 
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglRx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx 
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

It did return the screen resolution back, but still no Unity. 
Is there something what could I do?

My graphics card is:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 [Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series]
```

The output of lspci -k is

`VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 [Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series] Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device 9033 Kernel driver in use: radeon Kernel modules: radeon`

Comment: Can you give the relevant output of `lspci -k` (i.e check if the radeon driver is installed and associated with the card)?  Also, fglrx doesn't work with xorg 1.13, you would have to downgrade to 1.12.  In general, I would avoid the binary driver (fglrx) if possible; it tends to create more problems than it solves.

Comment: If the radeon driver is not installed, then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my issue. The output of `lspci -k` is `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 [Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series] Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device 9033 Kernel driver in use: radeon Kernel modules: radeon`. I also tried the installation of radeon driver, but apt-get says that both packages are there already.

Comment: They are installed and you are running the correct driver for your card.  What happens if you restart X?

Comment: When I switch back to lightdm, I cannot log in. I get the infinite loop of the greeter asking me to enter the password. Then the screen flashes for a while and the greeter is restarted. I noticed the log file though (`/var/log/lightdm`), and if I could, I would attach it or copy/paste the content of it. It seems that comments are restricted to such things.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Ok, here is the output from 3 log files: `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, `/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log`, `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log`, because the system writes in all three of them. [http://paste.ubuntu.com/1354060/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1354060/)

Comment: I can't find anything obvious in the logs.  Upgrades can be odd.  I would probably try reinstalling 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my wife's Asus A6 R series notebook. After upgrading to kernel 3.5.0-18-generic and uninstalling fglrx-legacy (`sudo apt-get remove fglrx-legacy`), it is working fine right now.

I upgraded the kernel just now and remembered uninstalling after seeing your post.
Output of `lspci -k` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 5a31 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 5a31
    Kernel modules: ati-agp
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS480 PCI Bridge
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 SMBus Controller (rev 82)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c-piix4
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 IDE Controller (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: pata_atiixp
    Kernel modules: pata_atiixp
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1339
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200M]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1392
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, radeonfb
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. L8400B or L3C/S notebook
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
    Kernel modules: 8139too, 8139cp
02:01.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b3)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
    Kernel modules: yenta_socket
02:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 17)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci-pci
02:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 08)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1397
    Kernel driver in use: r592
    Kernel modules: r592
02:03.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. A6U notebook embedded card
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

I hope this helps other people, too.

Comment: I have the same kernel version and I don't have fglrx-legacy installed either. Yet the problem exists :(